# MySQL - How do I open error/warning message list in a usable window?

Tags: mysql, windows-10, mysql-workbench

I got over 100 warning messages after running a script.  There's a single line at the bottom of the page that temporarily displays some of the errors when you place your cursor on it.  I can't find a way to copy *all* of the messages so I can past them in a text file and actually read them,  or open a window that has the errors.

I also don't understand why Google says nobody else has ever inquired about this.  I'm done banging my head over this (and other non-intuitive features of MySQL) - so, this post.

Thanks for any help.

(MySQL WorkBench 6.3.)

Comment: I have found a couple of references that say this is impossible.  And that's just hard to believe.  You can't develop if you can't read the error and warning messages.

Comment: If you have a script, you can execute line by line and see each and every error. Just hit flash with bar (Execute under Cursor)

Comment: Depending on circumstances, running the query `SHOW WARNINGS;` might work.

Comment: They are a wide variety of errors doing an import, so line by line won't help.

Comment: So, this question is about the error display in MySQL Workbench? Or about errors a specific script produces? Not clear here. Maybe you should add a sshot to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: It's about error display in MySQL Workbench.  I was explaining that doing a line-by-line execution won't help, as there in only one relevant executing line.